# Allow front-end User to access protected files

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I want to be able to allow certain frontend users to access protected files.  The frontend users is using https://github.com/rainlab/user-plugin

At the moment I can only see there are 2 options.  Public and Protected.  Public is too insecure as can be viewed by anyone and Protected is only available to backend users.

Is there any way I can auth a certain directory using routes.php in a plugin or solution to using User auth on protected files?

Here is an example of my route.php but not sure how to extend to auth.

```
$cmsStorage = AppConfig::get('cms.storage.uploads.path', '/storage/app/uploads');
$uploadsPath = $cmsStorage. '/privatefiles/{dir1}/{dir2}/{dir3}/{disk_name}';


Routes::get($uploadsPath, function ($dir1, $dir2, $dir3) {

// some login in here to return file


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/rainlab/user-plugin) of the plugin, you can restrict access to certain routes by applying the Auth middleware as such:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'RainLab\User\Classes\AuthMiddleware'], function () {
    // All routes here will require authentication
});
```

So you can easily protect those routes that return a file response by placing them in the route group above.